# Error authenticating with Fortify on Demand. Error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: azure-devops, devops, fortify, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I am trying to do automate build with fortify on demand extension embedded using Azure DevOps. The fortify task is throwing the error below - during the build

> [section]Starting: Run Fortify on Demand static assessment on Devops -
>   IISDeploy.sln

==============================================================================
Task         : Fortify on Demand Static Assessment
Description  : Submit code for Fortify on Demand security assessment
Version      : 3.0.2
Author       : Micro Focus

## Help         :

> ***[error]Error authenticating with Fortify on Demand. Error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate***

[section]Finishing: Run Fortify on Demand static assessment on Devops - IISDeploy.sln

Build Agent - MS Hosted Build Agent VS2017.

Authentication methods, I tried both Personal Access Token as well as API/Key Secret pair. None of the methods works. Is this because of any missing certificate.?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks much!

Regards,
Renji

Comment: I have not seen that error before.  The API key/secret is more mature than the personal access tokens, so stick with API key/secret.  You might need to open a help ticket with them to get this resolved.  Alternatively, you can try to debug stuff on your own from your PC (not from Azure) using [FoDUpload](https://github.com/fod-dev/fod-uploader-java/wiki/Running-Java-FoDUploader), which might help you figure out if the problem is on your side or the Fortify side.

Comment: @TheGreatContini - Thanks mate. Let me try with FODUpload, and keep you posted on this.